# Reseting the background color of a View

Tags: android, view, background-color

I'm trying to restore the background Color of a View.

I have several selectable Views. When the user clicks one of those Views, the following code is executed and the View becomes Yellow:

```
View newSelection, previousSelection;

...

if(previousSelection != null) {
    previousSelection.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); // problem here
}
newSelection.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

However, I want to reset the color of the previously selected View. However, I do not know which color it was (I'm setting it to Color.BLACK in the above code). I was not able to find a getBackgroundColor or similar method in the View class. If I had it, I could save the previous color and just put it back when the new View is selected.

Comment: If you just want to use the parent's background, you can remove the entire child's background with: view.setBackgroundResource(0);

Answer (score 6):

use View.**getBackground**(), it returns the current 'Drawable' background of the view which can then be used in View.**setBackgroundDrawable**()

```
View theView;
Drawable originalBackground;

...

originalBackground = theView.getBackground();

theView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

...
theView.setBackgroundDrawable(originalBackground);
```

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Android, setting background color might alter the original background ColorDrawable, so you should use `theView.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW))` instead

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but perhaps a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) would come in handy here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the previous color as a tag of the view.

For example

```
View newSelection, previousSelection;

newSelection.setTag(Color.Green);
previousSelection.setTag(Color.Black);

if(previousSelection != null) {
    previousSelection.setBackgroundColor((int)previousSelection.getTag());
}
newSelection.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

I haven't tried the code if there is an error but the flow on how to implement is there.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the original color of the View.

Comment: Are you not the one setting the original color of the view?

Comment: I'm not setting the original color because the original color is the default color used by android when no color is specified.

Comment: Then you should set it yourself. I suggest create a colorstatelist just like schwiz said. It is an xml file that contains colors depending on the state of a view. Just set it as the background of the view. By the way, can you try to elaborate more what you want to accomplish so that we can help you.